# Adding Column to Distribution List

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Can someone let me know how to add a column to a Distribution List. At the moment the only columns that appear are Name and Email.

Comment: Unless I am missing your point, this is a basic function of many office products. Right click on the column to which you want to insert a column to the left of and choose `insert` from the context menu. Is that what you are asking? If not, you will need to clarify what you are doing and give examples.

Comment: Hello Jonno, the macro is now saying there is only 1 member when there are over 150 members. I have tried re-adding the macro, but it still keeps on saying 1 member

Comment: Charlie, when I right click on the bar in the Distribution List I don't get the option to add another column

Comment: I'm sorry. I misread the tag. Thought is was excel. Obviously not much help for Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done.

The reason you only see the Name and Email is that other properties (like Phone Number, Title, etc.) are properties of Contacts, but Distribution List members are not Contacts. That is, they are not 'Contact' objects. They are instead 'Recipient' objects. And Recipient objects have only a few properties like this.

So you cannot add other columns here. You could write script or code that could gather additional properties, but your code would have to lookup the Recipient address in your Contacts (assuming they are defined there). For more details, check this out:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692878.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396